# pandas, unix timestamp to datetime python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

считываю csv файл, первая колонка идет unix timestamp есть ли способ быстро преобразовать дату в нормальный формат ? желательно сохранив в том же df. Еще вопрос по той же теме: данные другого столбца являются цифрами в строковом представлении, есть ли тут способ поменять формат для вывода на график (matplotlib)?
пример

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [1586390400000,1586383200000,1586379600000], 1: ['123', '321', '345']})
```

Comment: да, можно. да, есть. примеры исходных данных приведите в вопросе.

Comment: добавил пример.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({0: [1586390400000,1586383200000,1586379600000], 1: ['123', '321', '345']})
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
df[1] = df[1].astype(int)
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

Уточнение от MaxU - для таймстаймпа в миллисекундах, нужно сделать так:

```
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0], unit="ms")
```

```
                    0    1
0 2020-04-09 00:00:00  123
1 2020-04-08 22:00:00  321
2 2020-04-08 21:00:00  345

0    datetime64[ns]
1             int32
dtype: object
```

Comment: может все-таки `pd.to_datetime(df[0], unit="ms")` ? ;)

Comment: @MaxU, может :)